# How to populate a javascript array from a dropdownlist selected value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

**QUESTION**

How can I populate `myArray` with one of the arrays listed and change it using the selected option of a dropdown list?

*Using **javascript** or **jQuery***

```
<select id="ddl">
  <option>arr1</option>
  <option>arr2</option>
  <option>arr3</option>
</select>

var arr1 = ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    arr2 = ['1', '2', '3'],
    arr3 = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    array = document.getElementById('ddl').value;

//...
myArray: array
```

**PROBLEM**

Currently ddl is just a string value and I need the selected value to be one of the javascript variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an object to store your arrays in, then access that object using the string value of the dropdown. Something like this:

```
var options = {
    arr1: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    arr2: ['1', '2', '3'],
    arr3: ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
}
var array = options[$('#ddl').val()]; // options[document.getElementById('ddl').value]
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jku2hmbp/)

Answer (score 3):

You could make a multi dimensional array:

```
var arr = [];
arr['arr1'] = ['A', 'B', 'C'],
arr['arr2'] = ['1', '2', '3'],
arr['arr3'] = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'];

var selectedArray = arr[document.getElementById('ddl').value];
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cx0toL00/)

Answer (score 0):

What about that using the concept of @Rory McCrossan and adding the right values to the option?

```
<select id="ddl">
  <option value="0">arr1</option>
  <option value="1">arr2</option>
  <option value="2">arr3</option>
</select>

var options =[    
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['X', 'Y', 'Z'] 
];

$('#ddl').change(function () {

    var ch = $('#ddl').val();
    var array = options[ch];
    //test
    alert(options[ch]);

});
```

Comment: have you tested this ? I getting undefined as `array`

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to add `.val()` to the ch var assignation

Comment: edited my code, could you please delete the downvote? It's not the first time someone forgets some piece of code in copy/paste operation. Thanks

Comment: unfortunately I'm note the downvoter, but your code works, so +1 ;-)